# NVIDIA GeForce passthrough to VMware, code 43

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, nvidia-graphics-card

I have VMware ESXi 7.0.3 and a single VM with Windows 11 guest OS. The machine has a 1650 inside, which I’ve confirmed does not have a monitor attached. The bios has been configured to not post with the card. I have passed this card through to the VM.

Though the card is visible in Device Manager, Windows is using the VMware VGA adapter instead of the card. When I reboot the VM, I get an error code 43 from the device.

I was under the impression NVIDIA changed drivers around 2021 to [allow passthrough of a consumer card like this](https://nvidia.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/5173). Was I mistaken? Is there some basic configuration mistake I’ve made/something extra I need to do?

Comment: You do understand you must have at least two GPUs installed to acomplish what you want, right?

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to VM related things.  ESXi is old tech?  VMware Workstation is current?

Comment: ESXi 7.0.3 is older than the current version of VMWare Workstation.

Comment: OK.  We'll trial Workstation Pro in that case.

Comment: btw, we only need 1 GPU as we're using the web interface to access the host.

Comment: So I would be interested to verify there is a driver that specifically supports Windows 11.  However, "GeForce GPU passthrough supports 1 virtual machine. SR-IOV is not supported on GeForce. If you want to enable multiple virtual machines to have direct access to a single GPU or want the GPU to be able to assign virtual functions to multiple virtual machines, you will need to use NVIDIA Tesla, Quadro, or RTX enterprise GPUs.", means you can only have a single guest VM use the hardware.

Comment: Yes, we only  need one guest VM to use it.